# Page first load, options did not update, how to solve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I have two selection fields;

```
<label>Color:</label>    
<select id="color">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>

<label>Car:</label>
<select id="car"></select>
```

I would like to implement the feature that if color "**red**" is selected, update the `car` selection options to be **"red car 1"** and **"red car 2"**. If color "**Blue**" is selected, update the `car` options to be **"blue car 1"** and **"blue car 2"**.

I implement this feature in the following way:

```
var updateOptions = function(carField, options) {
    carField.empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        carField.append("<option value=" + options[i] + ">" + options[i] + "</option>");
    }

};

var colorField = $('#color');
var carField = $('#car');

colorField.change(function() {
    if (colorField.val() === 'red') updateOptions(carField, ['red car 1', 'red car 2']);
    else if (colorField.val() === 'blue') updateOptions(carField, ['blue car 1', 'blue car 2']);
});
```

Things are fine here. The only problem is, the `car` selection options get updated only if user select the `color`. The page first load **will not** update the `car` selection options. For example, "**red**" color is the default selected color when page loaded, but the car field is empty after page get loaded.  How to get rid of this efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this code: (outside any function)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#color').change();
});
```

Comment: @Mellon you can just add another `$(document).ready()` see the test case :)

Comment: Yes, it works, and I found that I can just call $('#color').change() without having "$(document).ready()" again, as I am already inside $(document).ready().

Answer (score 0):

While loading page make a call like this -

updateOptions(carField, ['red car 1','red car 2']);

Comment: No, if I select "blue" and refresh the page, car options will be "red car 1" and "red car 2", which is wrong.